# Visual studio 2019: Adding, Updating or Deleting Package Source Has No Effect

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I had a package source named MyMyGetFeed, I changed its URL but it still looking at the old one, even after deleting it I can still see that visual studio is looking into it as shown in the error message below, I'd also tried to create new package source with the new URL and it is still showing the same error neglegting my new source. Cleaning project, restarting Visual Studio and even deleting NuGet.Config file didn't help. Any Ideas please?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Synergix.WE.Security.Cryptography with version (>= 2.1.3)
  - Found 3 version(s) in MyMyGetFeed [ Nearest version: 2.1.2 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in nuget.org Synergix.ADCE.Client.Service.Commands   C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\source\repos\adce.client\src\Service\Synergix.ADCE.Client.Service.Commands\Synergix.ADCE.Client.Service.Commands.csproj   1
```

Comment: Please check whether your solution has a `nuget.config` file? The `nuget.config` file in soluton folder takes precedence over the global nuget.config file. Besides, how did you change the url, under Tools-->Options-->Nuget Package Manager-->Package Sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual studio 2019: Adding, Updating or Deleting Package Source Has No
>   Effect

**First**, if you add the new package source by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Sources`(global `nuget.config` file), you should make sure that there is no other custom `nuget.config` in your solution explorer to affect the global `nuget.config` file. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).

**Besides**, you can follow the below steps to troubleshoot your issue:

1. you should make sure that the new package source url is enable and the old package source url is deleted or unchecked like this:

   [image]

   In global `nuget.config` file(`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\`) like this:

   ```
   <packageSources>
     <add key="new package source" value="C:\xxxxxx" />
       <add key="old package source" value="C:\xxxxxxx" />
     </packageSources>
     <disabledPackageSources>
       <add key="old package source" value="true" />
     </disabledPackageSources>
   ```
2. From the error message, it searches for version `2.1.3`, so make sure that `Synergix.WE.Security.Cryptography 2.1.3` is in the new package source url and you have the right to access the new package source. To test it, you can copy the link in website to see whether it can return any request.
3. clean nuget caches under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General`-->`Clear All Nuget Caches` or just delete the `packages` folder under `C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget`.

   And run `nuget locals all -clear` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`
4. disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` in case it causes this abnormal behavior.
5. close VS instance, delete .vs hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, 'Nuget.Config' file under `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\`(will recreate automatically when restart VS)

   and then **run VS as administrator** to test whether the issue persists.

**In addition**, try to create a new default project and then install this package to test whether the issue is your project itself or is the nuget tool.